# PagedList Pagination

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pagedlist

I'm using PagedList in MVC . Everything works fine but the scenario goes like this.

Loading data from Stored Procedure.

So when an search condition satisfy SP returns 200 Records , Pagination goes like Page 1 2 3 4 ..  ( Actual wanted Scenario) which is working as expected and PageSize 20.

But when requirement changes

When Page 1 Click get 20 records , Page 2 get 20 Records and so on ( each click from Database ).. So on initial load SP will return only 20 Records rather than actual (200 records ) only one Pagination **Page 1 Appears**

But we know actual 200 records  pagination should be Page 1 Page 2 Page 3 it fails . So Pagination is created for only 20 records rather than actual number ie 200 .

Yes the work around is SP returns as output total 200 records so i know how many total records but how to overwrite 
 Html.PagedListPager to show Page 1 2 3 ?????

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep **StaticPagedList**  serves the purposes .

Few changes Required are :

```
var usersAsIPagedList = new StaticPagedList<CLASSNAME>(LIST, PAGEINDEX, PAGESIZE, TOTALCOUNT);
```

here TOTALCOUNT is 200 for your example.

While returning view make sure to return **usersAsIPagedList** and not as **usersAsIPagedList.ToPagedList**

```
return PartialView("_PARTIALVIEW", usersAsIPagedList);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use manual paging `StaticPagedList`,you have to modify SP to return the total number of records along with the results

This is an example quoted from "PagedList project" website :

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    public object Index(int? page)
    {
        var pageIndex = (page ?? 1) - 1; //MembershipProvider expects a 0 for the first page
        var pageSize = 10;
        int totalUserCount; // will be set by call to GetAllUsers due to _out_ paramter :-|

        var users = Membership.GetAllUsers(pageIndex, pageSize, out totalUserCount);
        var usersAsIPagedList = new StaticPagedList<MembershipUser>(users, pageIndex + 1, pageSize, totalUserCount);

        ViewBag.OnePageOfUsers = usersAsIPagedList;
        return View();
    }
}
```