# Use StaticPagedList with PagedListRenderOptions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, pagedlist

Using *PagedList* of MVC. Not able to get Property:

`PagedListRenderOptions { DisplayLinkToFirstPage = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded }`

Note that I'm using *StaticPagedList* not *PagedListPager*.

My Requirement is : [`pagedlist-pagination`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27600517/pagedlist-pagination/27613960#27613960)

**Not able to find syntax to use StaticPagedList with PagedListRenderOptions**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass the paging meta data as separate property and construct the `IPagedList` in the view. Like this:

```
public class PagedClientViewModel
{
    public int? Page { get; set; }
    public List<YourModel> ListofModel { get; set; }
    public IPagedList PagingMetaData { get; set; } 
}
```

And the `metadata` can be generated like this:

```
pagedYourModel.PagingMetaData = new StaticPagedList<YourModel>(pagedYourModel.Clients, 
pageIndex, pageSize, TotalCount).GetMetaData();
```

Then use the pager in view like this:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(
new StaticPagedList<YourModel>(Model.ListofModel , Model.PagingMetaData), 
page => Url.Action("ActionName", new { page }), PagedListRenderOptions.Classic)
```