# PagedList.MVC has an error in StaticPagedList with an invalid argument

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I am trying to use PagedList.MVC  I went to GitHub (https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList) and looked at the examples. I am Referring to "Example 2: Manual Paging".  When I use this code I get this error:

> Argument "1: cannot convert from 'System.Web.Security.MembershipUserCollection' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'"

Looking at StaticPagedList documentation, it does look to me like the first parameter is `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` and The sample code (below) for `var users` is of type `System.Web.Security.MembershipUserCollection` I need to find a way to get the first parameter to work.  I am not sure how to solve this problem.  (I have a "New Driver" bumper sticker.)

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    public object Index(int? page)
    {
        var pageIndex = (page ?? 1) - 1; //MembershipProvider expects a 0 for the first page
        var pageSize = 10;
        int totalUserCount; // will be set by call to GetAllUsers due to _out_ paramter :-|

        var users = Membership.GetAllUsers(pageIndex, pageSize, out totalUserCount);
        var usersAsIPagedList = new StaticPagedList<MembershipUser>(users, pageIndex + 1, pageSize, totalUserCount);

        ViewBag.OnePageOfUsers = usersAsIPagedList;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Go through below mentioned link

[http://stackoverflow.com/a/28190996/1390850][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28190996/1390850